# Serialising between versions

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I deserialise the object which got modified in new version.

---

For Example
I have a person class in my project for version 1.0.
Array of Person objects gets serialized when app is terminated

```
@interface Person : NSObject <NSCoding>
    @property NSString *name;
    @property NSUInteger age;
    @property NSString *location;
@end
```

This is how I am serialising my data

```
- (void)serializePersonList {
    NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:personList];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:encodedObject forKey:kPersonKey];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

---

Now I am planning to release version 2. And Person Class has been evolved to

```
@interface Person : NSObject <NSCoding>
    @property NSString *name;
    @property NSUInteger age;
    @property NSString *phone;
    @property KSAddress *location;
@end
```

Note

- Type of location has beed updated to KSAddress
- phone attribute has been added.

---

How do I make my app deserialize the old Person data ?

Comment: How are you serializing the data? It would be easiest to do it the way Wain says, but if you serialized it differently...

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you're using a keyed archiver. You write the code to connect the archived data for each key to the instance variable it belongs to. As you have changed type your code now needs to read the data into an `id` local variable, check the data type (`isKindOfClass`) and then either store the value or convert it to your new format and then store it.

Comment: Since I am serializing an array of Persons, will it create problem since the size of object will change, and hence offset of every object will also change.

Comment: That's why you should be using a keyed archiver. If you aren't then you have a problem.